# jQuery object VS object literal

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently on this JavaScript course on PluralSight and this came up.

It's a custom event handling lesson and he's about to show how to trigger events on regular objects (that aren't part of the DOM) and how to add event listeners to them.

**The context:**

Previously he was triggering the event straight from the `internalObject` itself, and now he is showing that you can centralize the process of many events in a so called `notifyObject`, and you can pass the `internalObject` as a parameter to the event handler function.

I have no problem with all the triggering and handling of those events.

**My question is:**

What's the point of creating a "jQuery object" (that's what he called it) using: `$( { ... } )`

Considering just the objects themselves, what's the difference between the `nofifyObject`, that was created using the jquery expression `$()` and the `internalObject`, that was created just as a regular JS object literal `{ }`?

Thanks already for your help!

[image: Advanced JavaScript course from Plural Sight]

[image]

EDIT: He was able to use the .trigger() and .on() methods on the `internalObject` created as an object literal. See picture below:

[image]

Comment: is  `INTERNAL` a custom html tag?

Comment: He has a function that display messages, and it shows the nodeName when the event is triggered by a DOM element (that usually has a nodeName). Now the event will be triggered by a regular object and he's just creating a nodeName property to be displayed by the function that will handle the messages. Otherwise it would be undefined.

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/jquery-object/
Found some good info in this link. I think it really doesn't make much difference, you just gain the jQuery methods convenience for that object.